# Problem with program that separates 2D array into even/odd 2D arrays (extra zeroes in even/odd arrays)

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, multidimensional-array

I am practicing with 2D arrays and am making a program that separates a 2D array with random integer values into two separate arrays based on if the values are even or odd.

However, the program seems to be adding additional zeroes to each row in the even and odd arrays. What am I doing wrong?

I think the problem is in the sort() function where I determine the size of the even and odd arrays but I am not sure.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] arr = new int[10, 10];

        // Fills 2D array with random values and prints them out 
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int y = 0; y < arr.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < arr.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                arr[y, x] = r.Next(1, 99);
                Console.Write(arr[y,x] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        // Function that separates original array into 2 separate ones (even and odd) 
        sort(arr);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void sort(int[,] array)
    {
        int j1 = 0;
        int i1 = 0;
        int j2 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;

        // Increases the size of the even/odd arrays whenever the value of the original array is even/odd respectively 
        // I think this is where the problem is
        for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                if (array[y,x] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    i1 += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    i2 += 1;
                }
            }
            j1 += 1;
            j2 += 1;
        }

        int[,] evenArr = new int[j1, i1];
        int[,] oddArr = new int[j2, i2];

        // Sets the values for the even/odd arrays 
        for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                if (array[y, x] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    evenArr[y, x] = array[y, x];
                }
                else
                {
                    oddArr[y, x] = array[y, x];
                }
            }
        }

        // Prints the values for the even array
        for (int y = 0; y < evenArr.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < evenArr.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                Console.Write(evenArr[y, x] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        // Prints the values for the odd array 
        for (int y = 0; y < oddArr.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < oddArr.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                Console.Write(oddArr[y, x] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your arrays (evenArr = new int[j1, i1], oddArr = new int[j2, i2];) the default values are zero. Since there's an extra zero it means you should check the length and probably reduce it by one.